# Behaviour of xTaskGetTickCount

Tags: freertos

With `xTaskGetTickCount` is it giving the tick count for just the current task or the number of ticks used for all tasks?  For example if I have

```
   TickType_t xT0 = xTaskGetTickCount();
   /// DO SOME STUFF
   TickType_t xT1 = xTaskGetTickCount();
```

and one tick is 1 ms, does `xT1-xT0` reflect the number of milliseconds of wall clock time that have passed or only the amount of CPU time spent to do some stuff, not counting the time other tasks have spent doing other things?

Comment: There is only 1 tick driving the scheduler. It has nothing to do with CPU load of tasks. See https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#xTaskGetTickCount